# How to resolve dependencies while installing application on linux (CentOS 7.1)

Tags: linux, centos, dependencies

When I tried install deluge on my CentOS 7.1 I was facing dependecy problems due to some el6 which are not meant for CentOS 7.1. So, I found this page:

https://gist.github.com/dasgoll/111f6f3364e2ab97bc08

---

His instructions:

#### Centos 7.1

yum -y install wget wget hxxp://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm

rpm -ivh nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm

yum -y install deluge-web

systemctl start deluge-web

systemctl stop firewalld

browse http://192.168.3.101:8112

#### check it

yum install deluge-console

---

And my question is: Why he installed "nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm" from li.nux.ro (if I'm not wrong it's a repository, correct me if I'm)? Because I had this dependency problem earlier when I tried installing deluge. But when I used his instructions it resolved all the dependencies automatically for me. So does this rpm file he installed on the first place was for resolving dependencies? If not then how can one work around with dependencies while installing a piece of software/application. Than You in advance.

P.S. I asked the same question in comments there too. But I'm uncertain of receiving reply there (no offence for the guy/girl - dasgoll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third party package repos will often use a *-release package to contain both a yum repo definition and a rpm signing public key so that end users can install packages directly from the repo using yum instead of having to find and then download them one by one.

Comment: Thank you for replying. What do you mean when you say repo definition? I don't have enough reputation to "vote up" for your answer. But it helped.

Comment: A configuration file that defines where the repository data is located so that yum can access it.